# Operation Precedence

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to store the result of a command into an array variable. I'm having trouble because the command itself contains variables that must be resolved before its execution. For example:

```
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do
     NEXT=$(( i + 1 ))
     MYARRAY[i]=$(cat $VARIABLE | uniq | sed -n '$NEXTp')
done
```

The "cat $VARIABLE" command is being processed correctly. The problem is with "$NEXT" substitution that is immediately followed by a "p" character. How can I force the script to resolve $NEXT variable before executing the command and store the results inside MYARRAY[i]?

Thanks.

Comment: `NEXT=$(( i + 1 ))` is the standard way to do arithmetic in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution is: `${NEXT}p`

Notice that what you are doing is fairly atypical.  It is more usual to assign to an array using something like:

```
IFS='
'
MYARRAY=( $( < $VARIABLE uniq | sed -n 1,5p ))
```

This will assign MYARRAY[0], which your original code does not do, but it's not clear to me if that is intentional or an attempt to adjust the indexing.  As always, UUOC is to be discouraged, and although `uniq` can take $VARIABLE as an argument, it's a good idiom to use the redirection so I'm using that in the example to demonstrate a simple way to eliminate UUOC in 99.9% of the cases it appears.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the 'p' to `NEXT` before using it in the expression:

```
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do
     NEXT=$(expr $i + 1)
     NEXT+='p'
     MYARRAY[i]=$(cat $VARIABLE | uniq | sed -n $NEXT)
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I also noted that it's not necessary to include the single quote character (') after the "sed -n" command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use script like this:

```
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do
     NEXT=$(expr $i + 1)
     MYARRAY[i]=$(cat $VARIABLE | uniq | sed -n $NEXT'p')
done
```